# Android Studio 0.3.1 Error : A prblem occurred while configuring project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

[image: Android Studio Error Message]

I installed Android Studio and developed my first application. I got this error. And in MainActivity.java also i find some errors.

[image: MainActivity.java]
How to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download all of the items listed in the SDK manager. Just go ahead and download all of them regardless of whether you think you'll need them. Every once in a while go back to the SDK Manager, refresh, and make sure everything is downloaded.